# jQuery call incorrectly firing at the same time as fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, call, jquery-callback

I am building a lightbox and am running into an issue where the following fadeIn function is firing at the same time as the fadeOut instead of afterwards.

Why is `updateImage.call(this)` firing at the same time as the `fadeOut`? Should it not fire afterwards considering it is placed as a callback?

[Full code snippet](https://github.com/Sntax/arc/blob/master/arc.js#L95)

```js
function updateImage() {
    activeImage = overlayImagesBox.find('.' + this.className);
    activeImage.fadeIn('slow').addClass('active-image');
}

imageLinks.on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!activeImage) {
        updateImage.call(this);
    } else {
        activeImage.removeClass('active-image').fadeOut('slow', updateImage.call(this));
        activeImage = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: You are executing the function instead of passing it as a callback. Does this solve your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/cchzoLh0/

Comment: Looks like you could just do `.fadeOut('slow', updateImage)`  as the context is passed to the callback. http://jsfiddle.net/0L83e0ec/

Comment: @blex I knew it was something simple, just needed a second set of eyes. Thank you for the help. That solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @blex mentioned in the comments the correct answer is simply passing the function as a callback instead of executing it. Thank you for the help everyone.